# Using each_slice to split input starting from end of string?

Tags: ruby

I would like to split a string into array groups of three as shown in *desired output*. Using `Array#each_slice` like this `1_223_213_213.to_s.split('').each_slice(3){|arr| p arr }`

```
Current output:                  Desired output
 # ["1", "2", "2"]                # ["0", "0", "1"]
 # ["3", "2", "1"]                # ["2", "2", "3"]
 # ["3", "2", "1"]                # ["2", "1", "3"]
 # ["3"]                          # ["2", "1", "3"]
```

Must work with numbers from (0..trillion). I posted my solution as an answer below. Hoping you all can give me some suggestion(s) to optimize or alternative implements?

Comment: "Gimme the code" with no attempted solution.

Comment: @maerics I posted my solution. See answer. And it's "feed me code", not "gimme the code" ;)

Comment: Good deal, thanks for that.  Typically you post your attempted solution directly in your question so that people don't think you're asking for others to do your work for you ;-)

Comment: feed, you may want to consider changing "I would like to split a string into array groups.." to "I would like to split the string representation of an integer into array groups..".  Careful readers might not find that necessary, but some of us are prone to misreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this a little more pleasing to your eye:

```
def slice_by_3(n)
  n = n.to_s
  l = n.length
  [*n.rjust(l % 3 == 0 ? l : l + 3 - l % 3, '0').chars.each_slice(3)]
end

slice_by_3 2_123_456_544_545_355
=> [["0", "0", "2"], 
    ["1", "2", "3"], 
    ["4", "5", "6"], 
    ["5", "4", "4"], 
    ["5", "4", "5"], 
    ["3", "5", "5"]]
```

Alternatively, if you want a more general solution:

```
def slice_by_n(num, n=3)
  num = num.to_s
  l = num.length
  [*num.rjust(l % n == 0 ? l : l + n - l % n, '0').chars.each_slice(n)]
end
```

Comment: To compute the padding size you should check if `l` is a multiple of 3, otherwise `9 + 3 - 9 % 3 # => 12`.

Comment: @wvandaal You answered quickest, your solution is elegant and actually works compared to some other answers. Thanks.

Comment: You could alternatively use `l+(3-l%3)%3` as the `rjust`'s first argument.  btw, `l%3` is here more pleasing to my eye than is `l % 3` :-).

Answer (score 4):

Try left-padding with zeros until the string length is an even multiple of your "slice" target:

```
def slice_with_padding(s, n=3, &block)
  s = "0#{s}" while s.to_s.size % n != 0
  s.to_s.chars.each_slice(n, &block)
end

slice_with_padding(1_223_213_213) { |x| puts x.inspect }
# ["0", "0", "1"]
# ["2", "2", "3"]
# ["2", "1", "3"]
# ["2", "1", "3"]

slice_with_padding(12_345, 4) { |x| puts x.inspect }
# ["0", "0", "0", "1"]
# ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for the problem:

```
def slice_by_3 number
  initial_number = number.to_s.split('').size 
  number = "00#{number}" if initial_number == 1
  modulus = number.to_s.split(/.{3}/).size
  padleft = '0' * ( (modulus*3) % number.to_s.split('').size )
  ("#{padleft}#{number}").split('').each_slice(3){|arr| p arr }
end

slice_by_3 2_123_456_544_545_355
 # ["0", "0", "2"]
 # ["1", "2", "3"]
 # ["4", "5", "6"]
 # ["5", "4", "4"]
 # ["5", "4", "5"]
 # ["3", "5", "5"]
```

Just seems somewhat complex and I want to believe there is a better way. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple methods

```
n = 1_223_213_213.to_s
n.rjust(n.size + n.size % 3,"0").chars.each_slice(3).to_a
```

OR

```
n.rjust(15,"0").chars.each_slice(3).drop_while{|a| a.join == "000"}
```

`15` is because you stated the max was a trillion obviously this number means very little as  it rejects all results that contain all zeros so any number greater than `15` that is divisible by `3` will work for your example

Comment: Just a note: 1_223_213_213 is not a string

Comment: @BroiSatse okay changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def split_nbr(n)
  str = n.to_s
  len = str.size
  str.rjust(len + (3-len%3)%3, '0').scan(/.../).map(&:chars)
end  

split_nbr(  1_223_213_213)
  #=> [["0", "0", "1"], ["2", "2", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"]]
split_nbr( 11_223_213_213)
  #=> [["0", "1", "1"], ["2", "2", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"]]
split_nbr(111_223_213_213)
  #=> [["1", "1", "1"], ["2", "2", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"], ["2", "1", "3"]]
```

Comment: Just a note: `1_223_213_213` is not a string.

Comment: @BroiSatse, thanks and ha! I'm so used to seeing strings without quotes in SO questions that my brain just added them. I see I was not alone. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def slice_by_3 number
  "000#{number}".split('').reverse
    .each_slice(3).to_a[0..-2].reverse
    .each { |arr| p arr.reverse }
end

slice_by_3 13_456_544_545_355
# ["0", "1", "3"]
# ["4", "5", "6"]
# ["5", "4", "4"]
# ["5", "4", "5"]
# ["3", "5", "5"]
```

This code reverses the whole array after adding 3 zeroes to the number start. `each_slice(3)` then slices to the proper groups (although reversed) plus one which consists of either `["0","0","0"]`, `["0","0"]` or `["0"]` depending on the original length of the number.

`[0..-2]` cuts the last group of zeroes. Then the groups are reversed back, and each group is printed (reversed back).